# Expo web build fails because of JSX in .js files

Tags: react-native, webpack, expo, react-native-web

I have a Expo project to which I added victory-native library. When building for the web, Webpack complains about missing loader. The errors are of this pattern below and appear for all the files from this particular library

```
./node_modules/victory-native/src/components/victory-clip-container.js 10:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| export default class extends VictoryClipContainer {
>   static defaultProps = Object.assign({}, VictoryClipContainer.defaultProps, {
|     groupComponent: <G />,
|     rectComponent: <Rect />,
```

How do I add the correct loader? Do I add something to the babel config? Or should I override the webpack configuration?
Babel is currently using only `babel-preset-expo`

Answer (score 3):

Whilst using `victory-native` in Expo apps that target iOS & Android is fully supported, we do not support building for the web with `victory-native`.

However, as both `victory-native` and `victory` share the same public API, it's possible to configure your Expo project to automatically use `victory-native` when building your native apps for iOS & Android, and victory when building your web app.

```
yarn add -D @expo/webpack-config
```

Then, create a **webpack.config.js** file at the root of your Expo project

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function(env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);

  // resolve victory-native as victory for the Web app
  config.resolve.alias['victory-native'] = 'victory';

  return config;
};
```

Refered from [the official documentation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/faq/#expo-web-apps-that-use-victory-native) .

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Michael, native and web code can be differentiated using the naming in the files.

A simple complete solution is:

victory.js:

```js
import * as Victory from 'victory';
export default Victory;
```

victory.native.js:

```js
import * as Victory from 'victory-native';
export default Victory;
```

And when you want to use the victory:

```js
import Victory from "./victory"; // this will default to victory.js or victory.native.js 
                                 // depending on the compilation target platform. 

const VictoryBar = Victory.VictoryBar;
const VictoryChart = Victory.VictoryChart;
const VictoryTheme = Victory.VictoryTheme;

...
{
...
    return <View style={styles.container}>
        <VictoryChart width={350} theme={VictoryTheme.material}>
            <VictoryBar data={data} x="quarter" y="earnings" />
        </VictoryChart>
    </View>
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, even WITHOUT the `config.resolve.alias['victory-native'] = 'victory';` line in webpack.config.js - so this answer is instead of the change to webpack config, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use victory-native imports for web and you cannot use victory import for react native.

I solved the issue by creating an file named victory.native.ts and victory.ts which containing all necessary imports.

victory.native.ts:

```
import * as Victory from 'victory-native'
```

victory.ts:

```
import * as Victory from 'victory'
```

Now you can import victory.ts in web and app.